# Disalbe Google tracking from links in PDF files created in google drive

Tags: pdf, google-drive-api, privacy

When I use "Download as PDF" option in Google Drive, google tracking code is added to the links. For an example his link:

```
http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp.html
```

becomes this:

```
http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apachefriends.org%2Fen%2Fxampp.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFtXe-IbwsOwmo74F41PYkDGCZLgw
```

Clicking on such link takes to google "you are being redirected..." page.

Is there a way to disable this other than not using Google Drive?